# Clean and conventional deadlifts: is one more advantageous?

Tags: deadlifts

Being aware about the differences in their respective [setups](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9566/barbell-deadlift-vs-clean-deadlift), I wonder if the clean deadlift is a more advantageous technique, compared to conventional.

A relatively advanced tip you start hearing when lifting heavy with the conventional technique is to drive with your legs, which I believe refers to quad engagement. Increased quad activation is one of the main things that make cleans different from conventional, so my intuition tells me that cleaning is a more advantageous technique when it comes to lifting heavier weights.

I know that hip and shoulder position are determined by individual morphology, and that many people are able to lift heavy from a more Romanian setup. But I wonder, for a person whose maximal quad activation is enabled by a clean setup/lift, is it true that a clean deadlift is more powerful than conventional? (Perhaps, that's why sumo is a thing)

Comment: The deadlift start position is a spectrum ranging from squat-like to SLDL-like. The strongest position for you would depend on the relative strength of your hip extensors and knee extensors. Olympic weightlifters are quad-dominant, which is why the clean deadlift comes naturally to them.

Comment: IMO the clean deadlift is not ideal for lifting the most amount of weight because the bar path is not vertical - the clean deadlift will force you to keep the barbell a bit further away from your shins, so the barbell has to travel backwards slightly.